# Pegar Variavel Combobox PHP

Tags: php, combobox

Boa tarde, Pessoal

Sou novo no assunto, e estou com problemas para capturar o campo selecionado pelo usuário em uma combobox para fazer uma alteração no banco a partir da seleção.

O código da página reincidente.php

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect('localhost','local','x','dblocal');
$query = "SELECT AcoesReinc from DescAcoes";

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaslot))
{
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TQA_DATA_CRIACAO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TQA_CODIGO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TQA_RAIZ']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_FABRICANTE']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_HOSTNAME']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_SLOT']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_PORTA']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['TAX_BAIXA_CAUSA_NOME']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$registro['VERIFICADO']."</td>"; ------> //aqui eu termino de montar o td do primeiro select e inicio o combobox para seleção do campo a partir de um segundo select 

echo "<td><select name='combo' form name ='combo' form action='consultareincidenteteste5.php' method='post'>";
            foreach ($dbconn->query($query) as $prod) {
echo '<option value="'.$prod['AcoesReinc'].'">'.$prod['AcoesReinc'].'</option>';
            }
    '</select>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>";'</form>';
    "<td>";


}}
```

Estou tentando enviar o que foi selecionado para o consultareincidenteteste5.php

```
 var_dump($_POST);
 $valor = $_POST['combo'];
 echo $valor;
```

Mas ela me retorna:

```
 array(0) { }
```

Gostaria de saber como posso armazenar o campo que foi selecionado no combobox pelo usuário.

Muito Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Você está colocando o form dentro do select? Crie um form fora do select

Comment: Você quer enviar somente os dados do combo box?

Comment: O form estava errado mesmo!! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
<?php 

$dbconn = mysqli_connect('localhost','local','x','dblocal');
$query = "SELECT AcoesReinc from DescAcoes";

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaslot))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TQA_DATA_CRIACAO']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TQA_CODIGO']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TQA_RAIZ']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_FABRICANTE']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_HOSTNAME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_SLOT']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TAB_PORTA']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['TAX_BAIXA_CAUSA_NOME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$registro['VERIFICADO']."</td>"; //------> //aqui eu termino de montar o td do primeiro select e inicio o combobox para seleção do campo a partir de um segundo select 
    echo "<form action='consultareincidenteteste5.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<td><select name='combo'>";
        foreach ($dbconn->query($query) as $prod) {
            echo '<option value="'.$prod['AcoesReinc'].'">'.$prod['AcoesReinc'].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>";
    echo '</form>';
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
```

Comment: Funcionou cara!! Muito obrigado!! Estava o dia todo nisso hehehe